# Perl I cant seem to figure out how to make this print out whats after the third <SEP> and delete everything before that

Tags: regex, perl

```
%TRMMMRR12903CF395D<br>SOJJAZT12AC4687219<br>Mike Badger and Friends<br>Autumn In The Mind (Acoustic Version)<br>
%TRMMMWA128F1462C8C<br>SOYNOIK12A6D4F7F3F<br>Sev Statik<br>All For A Purpose (Speak Life Album Version)<br>
%TRMMMKQ128F92EBCB5<br>SOOLRHW12A8C142643<br>Kreator<br>All of the same blood
```

above are a few examples of the lines I am reading and below is what I have so far.

It works fine and cuts out everything before the first `<SEP>` but whenever I try to modify it to make it reiterate through the loop or change to the third instance it just prints blank space for the whole file.

```perl
while($line = <INFILE>) {   
    foreach ($line){    
    $title =~ $1 if /<SEP>/;        
    print"$'\n";
    }   
}
```

Expected Result:
Autumn In The Mind (Acoustic Version)
All For A Purpose (Speak Life Album Version)
All of the same blood

and so on for larger files than just these 3 lines.

Comment: Why are you using `foreach ($line)` there? It doesn't do anything, because `$line` is a single string.

Comment: Also - what are you trying to get _out_ of this file?

Comment: My reasoning was to use it for each iteration of going through the file do this regex, which I guess now that I think about it was not the best route, haha.  I am trying to get just the song titles off of the end of each line.

Comment: Please post the expected result from your sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while( $line =<INFILE>) {
  my ($code,$code2,$artiste,$title,undef)=split(/\<br\>/,$line);
  print "$title\n";
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly thank you! Definitely showed me where I was going wrong too.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP explicitely asked for *everything* after  3rd sep.

Comment: @sebnukem yep he did but strangely that's not what he meant

Comment: `<` and `>` aren't meta-characters, so you don't need to escape them... `split(/<br>/, $line)` would work fine. An alternative to capturing all the other data would be `my $title = ( split(/<br>/,$line) )[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it - your sample isn't going to do much. The `while` loop reads a line at a time, but the `foreach` loop and pattern match doesn't do very much at all.

So at a basic level - you could just do something simple like this:

```
while ( <INFILE> ) {
    s/.*>//;
    print;
}
```

This chops off everything up to `>` - which works for the last line, but not the ones where you have a trailing `<br>`.

So instead - to avoid that happening, we say 'but not at the end of line':

```
s/.*>(?!$)//;
```

This gives us as output:

```
Autumn In The Mind (Acoustic Version)<br>
All For A Purpose (Speak Life Album Version)<br>
All of the same blood
```

So all we need do is drop `<br>` now:

```
s/.*>(?!$)//;
s/<br>$//g;
print;
```

This gives us:

```
Autumn In The Mind (Acoustic Version)
All For A Purpose (Speak Life Album Version)
All of the same blood
```

Whilst we're at it - you should really:

- `use strict;` `use warnings;`
- if you're opening a file, don't open `INFILE` instead `open ( my $infile, '<', input_file_name ) or die $!;`
- You can usually just use `<>` for simple cases - that reads `STDIN` or files specified on command line.
- for really simple applications, that means `-n` wraps your code in a `while ( <> ) {` loop. `p` is almost the same, but it automatically prints.

So:

```
perl -pe 's/.*>(?!$)//; s/<br>$//g' yourfile.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! and for the awesome walkthrough on how you were doing it! Still figuring out perl here so that is very helpful.